# how to pass a parameter to actionlink from a script

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, actionlink

I have a script:

```
function FindSerial() {
   var textBoxValue = $("#clientSerial1").val();

    return textBoxValue;
};
```

My actionlink is :

```
@Html.ActionLink("talks", "ClientTalks", "Talk", new { id ="FindSerial()" }, null)
```

I want to use the function in order to get id ; how can it be done?

Comment: It's not valid by this way. Because `C#` code gets execute on server side, while `JavaScript` code execute on client inside browser. Use Html `<a />` tag instate of `Html.ActionLink`.

Answer (score 0):

@Jalai Amini is right. You will need to handle it with jquery. Something like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("talks", "ClientTalks", "Talk", new { id="talklink"})

<script>
  $(function () { 
    $('#talklink').click(function () {
        document.location.href = $(this).attr("href") + "?id=" + FindSerial();
    }
});

</script>
```

**Something to consider:**

In this way you are creating the url in the client side, so it can't use the mvc routes. In my example, it will be putting the id as a querystring parameter, but it could be another thing.